# tensorflow.keras not utilizing gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, gpu

I'm using tensorflow.keras to train a 3D CNN. Tensorflow can detect my GPU. When I run the following code:

```
print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
print(tf.config.list_logical_devices('GPU'))
```

I get the following output:

```
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
[LogicalDevice(name='/device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

However, when I train my model I can clearly see in the Windows task manager that the GPU is not utilized at all.

Here is the code to build and train the model:

```
input_shape = train_gen[0][0][0].shape
model = Sequential()
# 1
model.add(Conv3D(8, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding='same', input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPool3D((2, 2, 1), strides=(2, 2, 1), padding='same'))
# 2
model.add(Conv3D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPool3D((2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='same'))
# 3
model.add(Conv3D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPool3D((2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='same'))
# 4
model.add(Conv3D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPool3D((2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='same'))
# 5
model.add(Conv3D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPool3D((2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='same'))
# final
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print('input_shape =', input_shape)
model.summary()

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(
    'saved-models/3d-cnn/best', monitor='val_loss', mode='min',
    save_weights_only=True, save_best_only=True, verbose=1
)

history = model.fit(
    train_gen,
    validation_data=val_gen,
    epochs=20,
    callbacks=[checkpoint]
)
```

Both `train_gen` and `val_gen` (which are passed to the fit method) are instances of a `CustomDataGenerator` class which inherits from `tf.keras.utils.Sequence` and generates batches of data by reading images from the disk and storing them in memory as a numpy array.

How can I make my model use the GPU during training?

---

Edit:

When I compile my model, the following output is shown in the terminal:

```
2022-02-21 16:38:59.667337: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-02-21 16:39:00.087775: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1510] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3989 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5
```

And I notice that I have 4.1 GB of my GPU memory allocated.

When I call `model.fit` I have two additional lines shown in the terminal:

```
2022-02-21 16:42:25.775427: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:185] None of the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2)
2022-02-21 16:42:27.101558: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:369] Loaded cuDNN version 8100
```

And I have 4.6 GB of my GPU memory allocated. The GPU utilization increases immediately to 100% for about 1 second and then goes down and remains at 0% for the entire training process.

---

Edit 2:

I entered the following command in my terminal during training: `nvidia-smi -l 5` and I got something similar to the following output (each 5 seconds):

```
Mon Feb 21 17:11:17 2022
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 496.13       Driver Version: 496.13       CUDA Version: 11.5     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ... WDDM  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   52C    P0    68W /  N/A |   4892MiB /  6144MiB |     70%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A     12176      C   ...bdul\anaconda3\python.exe    N/A      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The 70% value under GPU-Util kept changing between 70% and 85% during training. Does this indicate that my GPU is utilized?

Comment: are you using GPU on a server?

Comment: No, I train on my local machine

Comment: Yes this indicates that the GPU is being used, there is no problem at all here.

Comment: Yeah. I think the problem is that Windows Task Manager is showing false info about GPU utilization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Easy quick check whether GPU is being used:

run with `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="-1" ./your_code.py` if using python script or import os; os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'` in the code.

If you experienced significant change in nvidia-smi and/or speed/duration of the training, then you were using GPU in the first place. ( having `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="0" ( or "0,1,2" if on multi-gpu setting)

#### Short check list:

- Make sure you are importing and using `tf.keras`.
- Make sure you have installed `tensorflow-gpu`
- Watch GPU utilization with `watch -n 1 nvidia-smi` while `.fit` is running.
- Check version compatibility [table](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu). This is important.
- Ignore the cuda version shown in `nvidia-smi`, as it is the version of cuda, your driver came with. The installed cuda version is shown with `nvcc -V`.

#### In your case:

The model is getting loaded to GPU. So, it is not related to  your GPU utilization issue.
It is possible that your `train_gen` and `val_gen` takes time or they are buggy. Try without performing any specific augmentation to make sure the problem is not related to `*_gen`.

Comment: I tried this command `nvidia-smi -l 5`. I edited my question and included the output of this command. Please can you read it and tell me if my GPU is actually utilized?

Comment: @AbdulwahabAlmestekawy as you see there is one python process on your gpu, which takes 4.8 GB of it's memory this indicates the model/data is loaded on your gpu. 
The second indicator is that you have utilization, it's normal that utilization varies, meaning it's being used by your python process, if there are no other processes on it.

Comment: But why does Windows Task Manager tell me that the GPU utilization is 0% all the time?

Comment: I will leave for somebody else to answer, as I don't have any experience with training models on windows. But, a naive way to test if you are utilizing GPU is that you can make model train on CPU. you can do `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="" ./your_keras_code.py` if using python script or `os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'` in the code.  If you experienced significant change in `nvidia-smi` and/or spped of training, then you were using GPU without setting those params. @AbdulwahabAlmestekawy

Comment: check your cuda version with `nvcc -V` ignore the version of cuda shown on top of `nvidia-smi`.  you might have missed the short check list that I left in the answer. you should follow the compatibility table that I shared with you.

Comment: I tried `os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'` and the (estimated) training time increased from 4 hours to 182 hours! Obviously the GPU is utilized. I think Windows Task Manager is showing false information about GPU utilization. Thanks for your help. I will mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: Just want to add an additional comment to this answer. Your GPU is utilized, don't worry. You see 70-80% it means that (1) there are some bottlenecks somewhere (e.g. data processing time is slow) or (2) Your model is just...small to fully utilize GPU resources. This is completely normal.

Comment: 'watch' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.